# How to display the updated values of different tables using Stored procedure displayed Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

// Below update statement is present in my Stored procedure. I am passing two parameters (parameter 1 and parameter 2) while executing the Stored procedure. Once executing the Stored procedure i want the different updated values to be displayed. please provide the code for the below example(my stored procedure)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_TABLE(parameter1 IN NUMBER, parameter IN varchar2)
AS
BEGIN

   UPDATE Table1 SET column_a = (parameter1 +2) WHERE id= parameter2;
   update Table2 set column_b=  parameter1 where id=parameter2;

END UPDATE_TABLE
```

Comment: Why not just query the table once you're done updating it?

Comment: @Mureinik: i want the values to get displayed..There might be number of tables to be updated..

Comment: What do you want to be displayed? Updated column_a and column_b?

Comment: @EvgeniyK. yes the updated columns of the different tables

Answer (score 0):

Use `returning` clause + `bulk collect`. I don't know for what purpose you need this updated data to be displayed. Below approach for one of your table. You can share it to others.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE t_type is table of VARCHAR2(250);
    l_type t_type;
    begin
       UPDATE Table1 SET column_a = (parameter1 +2) RETURNING column_a BULK COLLECT INTO l_type;

       FOR i IN 1..l_type.count
        LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_type(i));
        END LOOP;
    END;
```